# Linux Mint with Rails + Apache/Passenger and MySql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, passenger

I read book "**Agile Web Development with Rails**" and stopped at the **chapter 16.1 about Apache/Passenger**. I need to install gem passenger and apache2-module. Gem been instaled succesfully but i cant tell the same about apache module.

Terminal:

**~ $ passenger-install-apache2-module**

```
Checking for required software...

 * Checking for GNU C compiler...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/gcc
    ….
 * Checking for Curl development headers with SSL support...
      Found: no
      Error: Cannot find the `curl-config` command.
    ….
      Location of httpd: /usr/sbin/apache2
      Apache version: 2.2.22
 * Checking for Apache 2 development headers...
      Found: no
 * Checking for Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers...
      Found: no
 * Checking for Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers...
      Found: no

    ….
Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.
--------------------------------------------

Installation instructions for required software

 * To install Curl development headers with SSL support:
   Please run apt-get (!!!) install libcurl4-openssl-dev or libcurl4-gnutls-dev, whichever you prefer.

 * To install Apache 2 development headers:
   Please install it with apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev

 * To install Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers:
   Please install it with apt-get install libapr1-dev

 * To install Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers:
   Please install it with apt-get install libaprutil1-dev
```

Ok, I try to install this required software, for example:

```
alexkd@Active-pc ~ $ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
[sudo] password for alexkd: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libidn11-dev but it is not installable
                        Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not installable
                        Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried a `sudo apt-get update`? You may have some broken packages. Also the passenger prompt gives `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` as an alternative option.

Comment: ~$ sudo apt-get update. Fetched 803 kB in 19s (41,8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>. What does this error means?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors

Answer (score 0):

I have the some problem, I resolve it with this command on Centos & Redhat:

```
yum install curl-devel
```

and In Debian & Ubuntu :

```
apt-get install libcurl-dev
```